# Categorize similar transactions

Tags: javascript

Please review the code to categorize some uncategorized objects:

```
const categorizeSimilarTransactions = (transactions) => {

    if (!(Array.isArray(transactions) && transactions.length)) return [];

    const uncategorized = [];
    const categorized = [];

    const orderIds = transactions.map(transaction => transaction.id);

    transactions.forEach(transaction => {
        transaction.category 
            ? categorized.push(transaction)
            : uncategorized.push(transaction);
    });

    uncategorized.forEach(uncat => {
        let lowestDiff = Math.min();
        categorized.forEach(cat => {
            if (cat.targetAccount === uncat.targetAccount) {
                lowestDiffComp = Math.abs(cat.amount - uncat.amount);
                
                if (lowestDiffComp < lowestDiff && lowestDiffComp < 1000) {
                    lowestDiff = lowestDiffComp;
                    uncat.category = cat.category;
                }
            }
        })
    });

    const merged = [...categorized, ...uncategorized];
    merged.sort((a,b) => {
        return orderIds.indexOf(a.id) - orderIds.indexOf(b.id);
    })

    return merged;
};
```

This is what a categorized transaction looks like:

```
{
  id: "bfd6a11a-2099-4b69-a7bb-572d8436cf73",
  sourceAccount: "my_account",
  targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
  amount: -350,
  currency: "EUR",
  category: "eating_out",
  time: "2021-03-12T12:34:00Z"
}
```

An uncategorized transaction does not have category property. This is what an uncategorized transaction looks like:

```
{
  id: "0f0ffbf9-2e26-4f5a-a6c0-fcbd504002f8",
  sourceAccount: "my_account",
  targetAccount: "eating_out",
  amount: -1900,
  time: "2021-03-12T12:34:00Z"
}
```

The following two transactions are similar:

```
{
  id: "bfd6a11a-2099-4b69-a7bb-572d8436cf73",
  sourceAccount: "my_account",
  targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
  amount: -350,
  category: "eating_out",
  time: "2021-03-12T12:34:00Z"
}
```

and

```
{
  id: "a001bb66-6f4c-48bf-8ae0-f73453aa8dd5",
  sourceAccount: "my_account",
  targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
  amount: -620,
  time: "2021-04-10T10:30:00Z"
}
```

**Example test Input**

```
categorizeSimilarTransactions([
  {
    id: "a001bb66-6f4c-48bf-8ae0-f73453aa8dd5",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: 350,
    time: "2021-04-10T10:30:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "bfd6a11a-2099-4b69-a7bb-572d8436cf73",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: -150,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2021-03-12T12:34:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "6359091e-1187-471f-a2aa-81bd2647210f",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: 100,
    category: "entertainment",
    time: "2021-01-12T08:23:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "a8170ced-1c5f-432c-bb7d-867589a9d4b8",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: -1690,
    time: "2021-04-12T08:20:00Z",
  },
]);
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    id: "a001bb66-6f4c-48bf-8ae0-f73453aa8dd5",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: 350,
    category: "entertainment",
    time: "2021-04-10T10:30:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "bfd6a11a-2099-4b69-a7bb-572d8436cf73",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: -150,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2021-03-12T12:34:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "6359091e-1187-471f-a2aa-81bd2647210f",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: 100,
    category: "entertainment",
    time: "2021-01-12T08:23:00Z",
  },
  {
    id: "a8170ced-1c5f-432c-bb7d-867589a9d4b8",
    sourceAccount: "my_account",
    targetAccount: "coffee_shop",
    amount: -1690,
    time: "2021-04-12T08:20:00Z",
  },
];
```

The feedback provided was

- inefficient code
- not readable

Comment: If this was an interview question could you please add the `interview` tag and maybe added `Interview Question` to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to disagree with @riskypenguin in two points of his otherwise great review:

## Partitioning

@riskypenguin suggests for partitioning the transactions into categorized and uncategorized to use `.filter()` twice. While his code certainly is concise, it is quite ugly IMO. Partitioning by a predicate  (at least this is the name I know it by) is a relatively common operation, so personally I'd extract it into a function such as:

```
function partitionBy(list, predicate) {
    return list.reduce(
       (acc, value) => {
           acc[!!predicate(value)].push(value);
           return acc;
        }, 
        {true: [], false: []}
    );
}
```

And then use it as:

```
const {true: categorized, false: uncategorized} = partitionBy(transactions, t => t.category);
```

## Performance

I believe the problem with this solution performance-wise is the merging and sorting at the end especially due to the use of  `.indexOf` in the sorting function.

Actually I'd suggest (unless there is expected to be a huge number of transactions) to avoid the partitioning and to simply loop over the original array twice, and use a guardian statement to skip over the "wrong" elements:

```
for (let uncat of transactions) {
    if (uncat.category) {
       continue;
    }
    for (let cat of transactions) {
        if (!cat.category) {
           continue;
        }
        if (cat.targetAccount === uncat.targetAccount) {
             // ...
        }
    }
}
```

(I prefer `for ... of` over `.forEach()`).

Or if partitioning is preferred then I'd suggest to only work with indexes so that the merging at the end can be avoided:

```
const indexes = transactions.map((_, i) => i);

const {true: categorizedIndexes, false: uncategorizedIndexes} = partitionBy(indexes, i => transactions[i].category);

uncategorizedIndexes.forEach(uncatIndex => {
    const uncat = transactions[uncatIndex];
    categorizedIndexes.forEach(catIndex => {
        const cat = transactions[catIndex];
        if (cat.targetAccount === uncat.targetAccount) {
            // ...
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Readability

I'd say your variable naming is alright, but there's some room for improvement.

I would expect `uncategorized` and `categorized` to refer to `boolean` or `string` values (in any case, it's not immediately clear), not an `Array`. Prefer `uncategorizedTransactions` and `categorizedTransactions`.

---

There's a bit of naming inconsistency between these lines:

```
const orderIds = transactions.map(transaction => transaction.id);
uncategorized.forEach(uncat => { ... });
```

This becomes even clearer after applying the first change:

```
const orderIds = transactions.map(transaction => transaction.id);
uncategorizedTransactions.forEach(uncat => { ... });
```

I would prefer this consistent approach:

```
const orderIds = transactions.map(transaction => transaction.id);
uncategorizedTransactions.forEach(uncategorizedTransaction => { ... });
```

---

`lowestDiffComp` does not accurately describe the variable at all. Its value has nothing to with `lowestDiff`. `transactionAmountDifference` or something similar would be clearer.

---

This block

```
const uncategorized = [];
const categorized = [];

transactions.forEach(transaction => {
    transaction.category
        ? categorized.push(transaction)
        : uncategorized.push(transaction);
});
```

is more concisely expressed as

```
const categorizedTransactions = transactions.filter(t => t.category);
const uncategorizedTransactions = transactions.filter(t => !t.category);
```

---

Initialize variables closer to where they're used. There's no need to initialize `orderIds` at the top of your function body. Simply move the line down to before `merged.sort(...)`, that's the only place you need it.

---

Now onto the bigger problems. Your function is too long and contains too many levels of indentation. With proper whitespace it's ~35 lines. A good rule of thumb is that a single function shouldn't be longer than 20 lines.

Long functions should be split into smaller functions, that each have a single responsibility. Take some time and think about proper separation of tasks and then move each of those tasks into a properly named function. This makes your main function a lot easier to read, and readers can easily jump into the smaller functions as needed.

This is already a very important tool to decrease the maximum level of indentation. You need to consider that each level of indentation is a layer of context the reader needs to keep track of in their head. There are different approaches to further reduce this, consider two refactorings of this code block:

```
array.forEach(element => {
    if (condition(element)) {
        console.log(element);
    }
})

// Option 1 - Exit Condition
array.forEach(element => {
    if (!condition(element)) return;

    console.log(element);
})

// Option 2 - Filtering
array.filter(condition)
    .forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    })
```

Now these examples are very simple and there's not a lot of nesting, but the concepts should have become clear.

### Performance

From the information you provided it's not entirely clear to me why the efficiency of your code is being criticized. The algorithm seems rather straightforward and I don't see any obvious shortcuts you missed.

Without specific instructions my approach is always to first (try to) write concise and readable code. You can then analyze and improve performance if it becomes an issue. You should of course avoid unnecessarily harming performance by e.g. making a linear algorithm quadratic. But as I said, nothing like that is jumping out at me at first glance.